# adding google places that will show in google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I have a problem adding the google places with the google place api.

When adding places manually with the url

http://www.google.com/places

its successfully added and the verification PIN is also received.
and the pending status is showing in our dashboard.
The above process is all OK,but i need the same thing to be done with the google places
"place actions" api.
link to the api :https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions

i have integrated this api with my code, and the places are successfully added(getting response OK) and also be found when using places search api.

But the major issue is that its not showing on the google map.
I have a bit confusion regarding,whether the places added with the above api will be viewed
in google map publicaly or it will be available only to the application that we have created.

Please provide me the solutions..so that i can add places in google map that will be found in google map when anyone searches on map publicaly.

Comment: "Please provide me the solutions" is not a question. What have you tried and where are you having problems?

Comment: i have added the new places with the google places api and the response that i get is "OK" but its not showing on google map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only requests submitted from a small number of trusted applications are being moderated for integration into Google Places. If you wish to add a new place that can be accessed outside of your application you can follow the Google Maps help instructions to [Add a new place](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144367&topic=1687361&ctx=topic).

If you are a business owner, you can add and verify your business on Google Maps using [Google Places for Business](http://www.google.com/placesforbusiness).

Another alternative to add places to Google Maps is to submit an edit through [Google Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) by following the [instructions](http://support.google.com/mapmaker/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1096044&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=1wf9zf83h3bs7&cbrank=2) from Google Map Maker Help.

Your added place will appear in Google Maps after it has been reviewed and accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,but i have one question,that what are the conditions that google follows that the application is trusted or not..